# Replace foreach with grep in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and I tried to replace my foreach-statement (version 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$cmd_list = "abc network xyz";
foreach my $item (split(" ", $cmd_list)) {
if( $item eq "network") {
    $PRINT_IP = 1;
    }
}
```

with a grep (version 2, from some example in the internet) which should give me the count (because of scalar context) of the value "network" in a string array:

```
$PRINT_IP = grep(/^$network$/, split(" ", $cmd_list));
```

for version 1 the if statement works as supposed, but for version 2 it always evaluates to false:

```
if($PRINT_IP) {
    ...
}
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: A belated welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  So that we can help you more effectively, would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52409380/edit) to include a self-contained script that we can run that shows the problem?  For example, what is the `$cmd_list` you are using as input?

Comment: Re "*of the value "network" in a string array*", The are no arrays anywhere in your code. It's counting the matching strings in the *scalars* (aka *list of scalars* aka *list*) returned by `split`.

Comment: Yet another problem that would probably have been a lot easier to track down if the program had included `use strict`.

Comment: I mean the value 'network'. Seems like a copy & paste error from the example.

Comment: $cmd_list is a string with values separated by spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a typo, as `$network` is a variable; you may mean `/^network$/`.

Having `use strict;` in your program would have alerted you to an untended (so undeclared) variable.  Having `use warnings;` would have alerted you to the use of an uninitialized variable in regex compilation.

In the loop you only set the variable `$PRINT_TP` (to 1) if there are any elements that match. Then [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) has a function just for that

```
my $PRINT_IP = any { $_ eq 'network' } split ' ', $cmd_list;
```

or

```
my $PRINT_IP = any { /^network\z/ } split ' ', $cmd_list;
```

if you need regex for more complex conditions.

This returns `1` on the first match, the result that your `for` loop produces. If you actually need a count then indeed use `grep`.  When there's no match `$PRINT_IP` is set to `''`, an empty string.

The library is more efficient, firstly since it stops processing once a match happens. You can also do that by adding `last` in your `if` condition but `List::Util` routines are generally more efficient.

More importantly: please always have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning.

Comment: The first any function call was just what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @user4711 You are welcome :)   Also keep in mind [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils), which has a lot more.